# How do I simplify the following command line options parsing code?

Tags: parsing, haskell, command-line-arguments

I am working on a homework manager for personal use, developing it with Haskell. I have, as a start, made the following code for parsing the commandline arguments, code which i should be easily extandable later through adding to `dispatch`. The functions themselves are dummies for testing purposes. I do, however, feel that this code can be made simpler, and more failsafe, though i cannot see how. The code is this:

```
module Main where

import System.Environment

main = getArgs >>= parse

parse :: [String] -> IO ()
parse [] = usage
parse (file:mode:[]) = if mode == "list"
                       then list file
                       else case lookup mode dispatch of
                         Just _ -> putStrLn "That mode requires arguments" >> usage
                         Nothing -> putStrLn "Please supply a valid mode" >> usage
parse (file:mode:args) = case lookup mode dispatch of
  Nothing -> do case lookup file dispatch of
                  Just _ -> putStrLn "Please supply a data file"
                  Nothing -> putStrLn "Please supply a valid mode"
                usage
  Just fun -> fun file args
parse (file:[]) = case lookup file dispatch of
  Just _ -> putStrLn "Please supply a datafile" >> usage
  Nothing -> list file

usage :: IO ()
usage = mapM_ putStrLn helptext

helptext :: [String]
helptext = ["Homework manager by Marcus Medom Ryding <mrok4a@gmail.com>"
           ,"Copyright 2013, licensed under BSD3"
           ,"Usage: homework filepath [mode] [arguments]"]

dispatch :: [(String, String -> [String] -> IO ())]
dispatch  = [("new",new)]

new :: String -> [String] -> IO ()
new file args = putStrLn ("NEW: " ++ file) >> mapM_ putStrLn args

list :: String -> IO ()
list file = putStrLn ("LIST: " ++ file)
```

Comment: If you want, I can show you how to use a command line parsing library to make your option parsing more slick.  Would you be interested in that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than parsing the command line manually, you should use a library.  Have a look at [cmdargs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs).

It lets you define command line options in a declarative fashion:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import System.Console.CmdArgs

data MyProg = New {comment :: String}
             | Delete {howMany :: Int}
               deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

new = New {comment = "this is a parameter with a default value"}
delete = Delete {howMany = 10}

main = print =<< cmdArgs (modes [new, delete])
```

This gives something like:

```
% ./prog new -c "hello world"
New {comment = "hello world"}
% ./prog delete              
Delete {howMany = 10}
```

You also get help for free:

```
% ./prog --help      
The myprog program

myprog [COMMAND] ... [OPTIONS]

Common flags:
  -? --help          Display help message
  -V --version       Print version information

myprog new [OPTIONS]

  -c --comment=ITEM

myprog delete [OPTIONS]

  -h --howmany=INT
```

The author also has a [nice tutorial](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/cmdargs/cmdargs.htm).  You'll want to do something similar to the "Multiple Modes" section.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial link. Am i right in the assumption that when using, for example `inputfile = def &= argPos 0` in a mode `new`, if i call `homework new "somefile.txt"`, `inputfile` will be `"somefile.txt"`? Or will it be `"new"`?

Comment: It will be "somefile.txt".  CmdArgs eats the "new" and routes the request to the New mode.

Comment: Thank you. That is what makes sense too (but you never know).

Comment: Oh, and one last question. How do i choose between `Implicit` and `Explicit`?

Comment: I've always used `Implicat`, since that's what's exposed by the top-level module: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cmdargs/0.10.3/doc/html/System-Console-CmdArgs.html

Comment: Also, all the tutorials I've seen focus on `Implicit`.  I can't comment on `Explicit`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer, just based on your code:

```
module Main where

import System.Environment

main∷ IO ()
main = getArgs »= parse2

parse2 ∷ [String] → IO ()
parse2 [] = usage
parse2 (file:mode:[])
    | mode ≡ "list" = list file
    | mode ≠ "list" =
    case lookup mode dispatch of
        Just _ → putStrLn "That mode requires arguments" » usage
        Nothing → putStrLn "Please supply a valid mode" » usage
parse2 (file:mode:args) =
    case lookup mode dispatch of
        Nothing → err (lookup file dispatch) » usage
        Just fun → fun file args
        where err (Just _) = putStrLn "Please supply a data file"
              err Nothing = putStrLn "Please supply a valid mode"
parse2 (file:[]) =
    case lookup file dispatch of
        Just _ → putStrLn "Please supply a datafile" » usage
        Nothing → list file

usage ∷ IO ()
usage = mapM_ putStrLn helptext

helptext ∷ [String]
helptext = ["Homework manager by Marcus Medom Ryding <mrok4a@gmail.com>"
           ,"Copyright 2013, licensed under BSD3"
           ,"Usage: homework filepath [mode] [arguments]"]

dispatch ∷ [(String, String → [String] → IO ())]
dispatch  = [("new",new)]

new ∷ String → [String] → IO ()
new file args = putStrLn ("NEW: " ⧺ file) » mapM_ putStrLn args

list ∷ String → IO ()
list file = putStrLn ("LIST: " ⧺ file)
```